# how to sort csv file with two columns in c#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, csv

my csv files have 14 columns and ~800.000 lines. I must sort csv orderby 10th column thenby 3rd column.
I use below code but sorts by only 10th column

```
            string filePath = "D:\\csv.csv";

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath, Encoding.Default);

            var data = lines.Skip(1);
            var sorted = data.Select(line => new
            {
                SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(';')[9]),
                 Line = line

            }
            ).OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).Select(x => x.Line);
            File.WriteAllLines("D:\\sortedCsv.csv", lines.Take(1).Concat(sorted), Encoding.Default);
```

my csv likes

- **col1 ; col2 ; col3 ;......; col10; ..**
- abc  ; fds ;123456 ;.... ;123  ; ..
- def  ;  dsa ; 12435 ; .... 124  ;   ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sorted = data.Select(line => new
{
    SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(';')[9]),
    SortKeyThenBy = Int32.Parse(line.Split(';')[2]),
    Line = line
}
).OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).ThenBy(x => x.SortKeyThenBy)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)`:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath, Encoding.Default);
var data = lines
           .Skip(1)
           .Select(l => new{Fields = l.Split(';'), Line = l})
           .Where(x => x.Fields.Length == 14 && x.Fields[9].All(Char.IsDigit))
           .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Fields[9]))
           .ThenBy(x => x.Fields[2])
           .Select(x => x.Line);
File.WriteAllLines("D:\\sortedCsv.csv", lines.Take(1).Concat(data), Encoding.Default);
```

Note that `File.ReadLines` is more efficient than `File.ReadAllLines` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use thenBy after the first OrderBy

```
            var sorted = data.Select(line => new
            {
                SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(';')[9]),
                 Line = line

            }
            ).OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).ThenBy(x => x.Line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sorted = data.Select(line => new
        {
            SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(';')[9]),
            SortKey2 = line.Split(';')[2],
             Line = line

        }
        ).OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).ThenBy(x=>x.SortKey2).Select(x => x.Line);
```

Basically add your second sorting criterion and then sort in the specified order.