# Can I sort date in a csv text document with a button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to sort the dates in the `csv` that is saved in my text document with following format:

```
EventName1, EventType1, 05-06-2019, Location1, Details1
EventName2, EventType2, 05-06-2019, Location2, Details2
EventName3, EventType3, 05-06-2019, Location3, Details3
```

and so on.
The sort will be done by a button, and will be viewed on a listview.

I have successfully completed sorting by letter, and showing on the `listview`.

```
//SORTS THE DATA IN ASCENDING ORDER
string inFile = @"Events.txt";
var contents = File.ReadAllLines(inFile);
Array.Sort(contents);
File.WriteAllLines(inFile, contents);

//CLEARS EVERYTHING IN THE LISTVIEW
listView1.Items.Clear();

//OPENS THE DATA AGAIN IN THE LISTVIEW AFTER BEING SORTED
foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"Events.txt"))
{
    // Split only the single line
    string[] lineItems = line.Split(',');

    ListViewItem listView1 = new ListViewItem();
    listView1.Text = lineItems[0];
    listView1.SubItems.Add(lineItems[1]);
    listView1.SubItems.Add(lineItems[2]);
    listView1.SubItems.Add(lineItems[3]);
    listView1.SubItems.Add(lineItems[4]);
    this.listView1.Items.Add(listView1);
}
```

I have tried doing this but for the dates, and I haven't got far. I'm trying to sort dates from first to last, but I can't figure out the code.

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368681/sorting-an-array-of-strings-containing-dates-by-dates-descending

Comment: My suggestion, use a JSON to store your data, if you need a text file (so you'll also better handle dates as DateTime objects instead of strings). The ListView controls has sorting capabilities built in. You can sort by column or whatever. There's a complete example in the Docs, related to the ListView [ListViewItemSorter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the date column that you will `OrderBy` and then use `DateTime.Parse`
you can see these examples [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296037/how-to-sort-csv-file-with-two-columns-in-c-sharp) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368681/sorting-an-array-of-strings-containing-dates-by-dates-descending)

You can run the code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJ22C5YMr)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines(@"f.txt");

            var sorted = contents.Select(line => new
            {// Make sure that you use the index depend on your line
                SortKey = DateTime.Parse(line.Split(',')[2]),

                Line = line

        }
                  ).OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).ToList();


            sorted.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code will work for what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to sort a text document which contains data separated with commas, and I would like to sort by dates.

Comment: @Scretqer This code extract the date from the text and order it by the extracted date. This answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to sort your csv file like below(make sure you have a using for System.Linq):

```
var orderedCsv = File.ReadLines(@"Events.txt")
            .OrderBy(f => f.Split(',')[2]).ToList();
```

You read in your lines and then using order by with the field you want which is the 2nd in the 0 based split you can push to a list. Then you can loop through the ordered csv and add it to your listview

```
foreach (var line in orderedCsv)
        {
            // Split only the single line
            var lineItems = line.Split(',');

            var listView1 = new ListViewItem {Text = lineItems[0]};
            listView1.SubItems.Add(lineItems[1]);
            listView1.SubItems.Add(lineItems[2]);
            listView1.SubItems.Add(lineItems[3]);
            listView1.SubItems.Add(lineItems[4]);
            listView1.Items.Add(listView1);
        }
```

Comment: this code works, but how would you make this sort only dates (05-06-2019). I have dates in a text document with the format of csv, like i mention at the start of this question. I want the dates to be sorted from most upcoming date to the date further away.

Comment: This code will sort by earliest date to latest date. How else are you trying to sort? Provide an example that has various dates in different orders and then the order you want it to be in